# IOS - unwanted hyperlink in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

got this html that i insert as string to uiwebview

```
<div style="font-family: sans-serif;">

<p><p><u>George Barret</u>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Irish,
1728/1732-1784&nbsp;</p>

<p><b><i>An Extensive Wooded River Landscape
with Fishermen Hauling in their Nets in the Foreground</i></b><b>, </b></p>

<p><b>1760s</b></p>

<p>Oil on canvas<br><span style="font-size: 13.513513565063477px; line-height: 19.988739013671875px;">137 x 195.5 cm</span></p>

<p>Heritage Gift, IIB Bank, 2005</p>

<p><span>NGI.4750</span></p></p></div>
```

i got a blue hyperlink on "1728/1732-1784"

anyone know why and how can i disable this behavior ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`myWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;`

This will prevent your `UIWebView` from converting anything (phone numbers, links, email addresses) into clickable links. The attribute `detectorTypes` is a bitmask, and you can specify any or all of the following values OR'd together:

```
 enum {
   UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber   = 1 << 0,
   UIDataDetectorTypeLink          = 1 << 1,
   UIDataDetectorTypeAddress       = 1 << 2,
   UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent = 1 << 3,
   UIDataDetectorTypeNone          = 0,
   UIDataDetectorTypeAll           = NSUIntegerMax
};
```

For example, to turn only email addresses and phone numbers into clickable links you would use:

```
myWebView.dataDetectorTypes = 
    UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber | UIDataDetectorTypeAddress;
```